# Android calendar app that allows for fine-grained daily planning

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar

I want to do fine-grained daily planning.

The first half an hour of the day might be:

> 7:00-7:15 Showering
>   7:15-7:17 Brushing Teeth
>   7:17:7:20 Getting dressed
>   7:20-7:30 Breakfast

Unfortunately, the default Android calendar app only gives limited space for an hour and not enough to display all these tasks underneath each other with their start and stop times.

I would want the calendar app to still sync with my Google Calendar. Is there an App for Android that fulfills my needs?

Comment: While there's a minute missing in your schedule ("7:17-7:18 Rinse Teeth & clean brush" ;)… I've never tried such a tight schedule. Be welcome to check my [app lists for Android calendars](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_general). I'm using *Business Calendar* (paid version) and am quite satisfied with it. As it allows "zooming", I could imagine it would fit your needs (free version available to find out). It uses any calendar backend available, so you can sync it with GCal as required. // Apart from that: What's your price margin?

Answer (score 1):

The "Schedule" (or "Agenda" view) of the standard android calendar app gives you a list of calendar entries as you describe. These particular views allow for fine-grained small entries while maintaining visibility of the detail.

The only downside is that because it is a list you lose the relative positioning of the cards to show early morning vs late evening for example.

Answer (score 0):

**SolCalendar.** For long time I have searched for a calendar on Android (with Google calendar sync) that would be comfortable and flexible and came to using SolCalendar. It allows what you want and additionally it many other helpful features, e.g. it has to-do lists with notifications (!)